# Selection of text as starting point of an algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I 've some troubles to figure out how to make the act of selecting or clicking a word in a text a call to action for other functions

I explain myself with the following pseudo-code of what I would like to do:

```
word_selected= recognition_of_selected_word_function()
if(word_selected) 
      function1(word_selected)
      function2(word_selected)
      function3(word_selected)
```

Is there any function which could fit as "recognition_of_selected_word_function()"?

As an example, I've seen that the google translator extension has something similar. You select some text, and it start his own script.
[selection of text as starting point of an algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHiNq.png)

I've been searching for something similar with goggle for a week...but nothing...

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense. You don't even say where *"the act"* will be taking place. Is this a GUI? A web application?

Comment: Where do you get the `word_selected` from? Where is the bound function executed from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone would have the same problem, I 've found the solution in another stackoverflow question [Mouse events on text in Python using wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927178/mouse-events-on-text-in-python-using-wxpython)